# Artifical Neuron's Output

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

In the iteration1 image of the following wiki you can see a basic neural network:
http://www.heatonresearch.com/wiki/Back_Propagation

If you look at the hidden layer's first neuron (H1) you'll notice that the sum is: -0.5313402159445314
and the output is: 0.3702043582229371

What I can't figure out is how the output was calculated. If I use sigmoid or hyperbolic tangent function on the sum value i get different results.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are using the [Sigmoid activation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function).

The formula is 1/(1+exp(-x)).

We can check in Python via:

```
from math import exp
x=-0.5313402159445314
print 1./(1.+exp(-x))
```

Prints 0.370204358223

Comment: thanks, I found where my problem was (javascript):
1.0 / 1.0 + Math.exp(-x)
was wrong and should be:
1.0 / (1.0 + Math.exp(-x))